# Performing two replacements in Makefile with $(VAR:.x=.y)

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile, I observe that I can use the pattern `$(VAR:.x=.y)` to perform a replacement, but can I perform two replacements in the same call?

Specifically, I wish to modify a rather long Makefile written by someone else, which includes the compiler flag `-Wa,-adhlns=$(<:.c=.lst)`. Since I have both .c and .cpp files going under the hammer with a single set of compiler flags, I'd like to apply the foregoing replacement to both those extensions. (As it is, my .cpp files are getting overwritten.)

I've tried `-Wa,-adhlns=$($(<:.c=.lst):.cpp=.lst)`, but that doesn't work. Is my aim at all possible?

Comment: Could you show us the whole rule?

Comment: @Beta, the rule gets built gradually. If you really want to see the whole thing (even though it doesn't exist in the Makefile all in one place), I can try to track it down, but I think you may just care about this part: `ALL_CFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:.c=.lst)`.

Comment: Substitution references are a shortcut for `$(patsubst ...)`. `${VAR:.x=.y}` is shorthand for `$(patsubst ${VAR},%.x,%.y)`. You can do what you ask with `$(patsubst $(patsubst $<,%.cpp,%.lst),%.c,%.lst)`. MadScientist's answer is clearly the way to go though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like that, but you can do this:

```
$(addsuffix .lst,$(basename $(VAR))
```